# CSS Flex not working on iphone 5

Tags: ios, css, flexbox

I have the following css and everything is display properly apart from the flex setting of justify content isnt spacing the items evenly across the whole screen?

```
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 568px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait) {

.container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
        -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-evenly;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 3% 0;
}

h2 {
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.logo {
    height: 30%;


 }


.text {
}

.icons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.icon1 {
    width: 25%;
}

.icon2 {
width: 25%;
}

.icon3 {
    display: none;
}

.icon3m {
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('images/insta small.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
}

.icon3m a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

.textbreak {
    display: block;
}

}
```

Cant figure out why it isnt working as it is loading correctly and even changed h1 color value to red to see if the css is working and it is

Comment: `space-evenly` doesn't work cross browsers yet. If you want a proper answer you need to provide a working code snippet, not only CSS.

Comment: Thanks, just changed it to center and has worked fine, now to redefining all margins and padding for spacing it out now ha. Thanks again